# HTML `products.sort()` function isn’t working?

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

Basically I am trying to make it so my variable is sorted in alphabetical order. The thing is my variable has a lot of words in it.

```
<button type="button" onclick="func1()">Alphabetize!</button>
```

```js
var products = ['Printer', 'Tablet', 'Router', 'Computer', 'Laptop', 'Phone', 'TV'];
document.getElementById('varproducts').innerHTML = products;
function func1() {
  products.sort();
  document.getElementById('varproducts').innerHTML = products;
}
```

The problem is that when I click the "Alphabetize" button it changes the order of the words but it doesn’t do it alphabetically. The result I get is:

```
"Phone,Computer,Laptop,Printer,Router,TV,Tablets."
```

My code was working perfectly but I made it slightly shorter and now it wont print out alphabetically. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I regret to inform that HTML is not a programming language (it's just a markup language, so you cannot write programs with it). The code you've shared appears to be JavaScript, so I've re-tagged the question accordingly.

Comment: varproducts - i guess it is typo, should be var products? Btw, code is working, problem is somewhere else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in the comments there is a typo in your code:

```
    <button type = "button"
    onclick = "func1()">
    Alphabetize!</button>
    <script>
    // var products not varproducts
    var products= ["Printer","Tablet","Router","Computer","Laptop","Phone","TV"];
    document.getElementById("varproducts").innerHTML = products;
    function func1() {
      // products.sort() not varproducts.sort()
      products.sort(); document.getElementById("varproducts").innerHTML = products; 
    }
</script>
```

`varproducts` is your **div element id**
`products` is a **javascript variable** declared using the keyword var

Comment: Deleted my answer, one is enough :D